# .Net maui layout is not updating when toggling visibility between grids inside

Tags: c#, .net, maui

This is my xaml in the code I have an absolute layout with a vertical stack layout containing 2 grids with different heights toggling between the visibility to show one of them on toggle layout does not update the height of the vertical layout fo that white space appears

```xml
<AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="layout" IsVisible="{Binding IsGridVisible}">

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" RowDefinitions="*" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,400,800" >
        <ContentView Content="{Binding Custom}" />
    </Grid>

    <VerticalStackLayout BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
            x:Name="actionBar"
            VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,1,400,300"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" >

        <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="notAssignedGrid"
                IsVisible="{Binding Service.IsAssigned,Converter={StaticResource InvertedBoolConverter}}"
                HeightRequest="200"  >
            <Frame HeightRequest="50"  Padding="0" x:Name="myFrame" >
                <Label  Text="{Binding StatusText}" 
                        FontSize="Medium"
                        VerticalOptions="Start"
                        Margin="0,10,0,0"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            </Frame>
            <Frame x:Name="stopButton"  BackgroundColor="Yellow"
                    HeightRequest="65"
                    CornerRadius="100"
                    Background="#df1801"
                    BorderColor="Transparent"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    Padding="6,10,10,10"
                    WidthRequest="65" >
                <Image Aspect="AspectFill"
                        HeightRequest="30"
                        WidthRequest="30"
                        Source="stop.png"/>
                <Frame.GestureRecognizers >
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding SwitchStatusCommand}"/>
                </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            </Frame>
            <BoxView VerticalOptions="End"
                    Color="White"
                    HeightRequest="5"/>
        </Grid>
    
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="assignedGrid" IsVisible="{Binding Service.IsAssigned}" RowDefinitions="auto,*" 
                Padding="0" Margin="0" BackgroundColor="red" >
            <Frame Grid.Row="0" 
                    BorderColor="White"
                    CornerRadius="60"
                    HeightRequest="1"
                    TranslationY="-5"
                    Margin="0,0,0,0"
                    Padding="0">
            </Frame>
            <Grid IsVisible="{Binding Service.IsDropOff,Converter={StaticResource InvertedBoolConverter}}">
                <VerticalStackLayout HeightRequest="500" Grid.Row="1"  TranslationY="-20" >
                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    
    </VerticalStackLayout>
    
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

my C# code showing how to toggle the visibility the UI is being updated showing the grid that is toggled but the layout is messed up

```cs
public async Task SwitchIsAssigned()
{
    _isAssigned = !_isAssigned;        
}
```

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

My issue was fixed apparently it was related to using the Navigation.PushModalAsync() not sure why I think it's a bug changing the layout after pushing and popping the modal created this issue is solved by navigating to the page rather than pushing as a modal the layout is then updated to the auto size after adding this change

Comment: you appear to be updating the private backing field, not the **public property** `IsAssigned` that UI is bound to

Comment: your right but this wasn't affecting my code the UI is currently being updated my main problem is that the layout is not updating  according to the grid's height
thanks for mentioning that

Comment: Not an answer to your questions but maybe is related. Do not use frame is obsolete (use border instead).
Also, when you set visible=false, doesnt mean that the height is set to zero. May be is worth playing with heightrequest and maxheightrequest. Also i would suggest to change the container to another control eg border, grid.

Comment: Thanks for your help issue was fixed as explained in original question

Answer (score 1):

- `Grid.Row=...` has no effect, unless the immediate parent is `Grid`. Not `VerticalStackLayout`. Not `AbsoluteLayout`.

I would make layout without those, in a parent Grid:

```xml
<Grid RowDefinitions="*,Auto" ...>
  <ContentView Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding Custom}" />

  <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="notAssignedGrid" HeightRequest="200" ...>
    ...
  </Grid>

  <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="assignedGrid" ...>
    ...
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I've guessed that you are trying to give Row 0 whatever space is not used by Row 1.  If that isn't correct, add to question a description of the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution to this question 
this is exactly what i meant with the grid layout.
I changed the layout to an absolute layout due to having the same problem with grid layout my issue was fixed apparently it was related to using the Navigation.PushModalAsync() not sure why i think it's a bug changing the layout after pushing and popping the modal created this issue solved it by navigating to the page the layout is then updated to the auto size